# How to execute the script under a condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to execute the script only when it satisfies the condition.

If Column1 is not blank then only we can use the below script else will print the message. I have tried several ways but couldn't find the possible way to work.

**Sheet1**

```
id_number  company_name        match_acc

IN2231D    AXN pvt Ltd
UK654IN    Aviva Intl Ltd
           Ship Incorporations
LK0678G    Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd
NG5678J    Nokia Inc
```

**Sheet2**

```
identity_no   Pincode   company_name

 IN2231        110030    AXN pvt Ltd
 UK654IN       897653    Aviva Intl Ltd
 SL1432        07658     Ship Incorporations
 LK0678G       120988    Oppo Mobiles Pvt Ltd
```

**Script i have been using**

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')

if df1[['id_number']] is not NaN:
  cross = df1[['id_number']].merge(df2[['identity_no']], how='cross')
  cross['match_acc'] = cross.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.id_number, x.identity_no), axis=1)
  df1['match_acc'] = df1.id_number.map(cross.groupby('id_number').match_acc.max())
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
filtered = df1[df1['id_number'] != ""]
```

then use the `filtered` variable for the rest of your code

Comment: Its not working as per mentioned, Is there any possibility of creating the script in function and calling the function in an condition, but dont know how to do it.

Comment: How can we execute the same using an function.

Comment: if possible, could you please attach the excel here, will try to create a function for you

Comment: Sir, I have already shared the sample dataset with which we can create a function.

Answer (score 0):

The id_number may just be an empty string and not necessarily NaN:

I usually resort to this while checking for empty column:

```
df[ (df[column_name].notnull()) & (df[column_name]!='') ]
```